# What ground cover plants can thrive under my rain barrel spigot?

Tags: lawn, plant-recommendations, ground-cover

I have a rain barrel with a spigot in my yard.  I try to be careful, but the ground around the spigot is taking a beating.  It gets pounded by water from the spigot and I tread on it frequently and while wet.  I'm starting to kill the miscellaneous grasses and compact the already heavy clay soil around the spigot.

I prefer to keep plants living there instead of laying down a few rocks.  Are there any plants that can tolerate this?

- Frequent / excessive watering
- Foot traffic
- Partial shade
- Heavy clay soil
- Grow in Gardening Zone 6

Comment: You're looking for a bionic plant! Some weeds approach bionic strength, but be careful what you wish for.  Bindweed comes to mind.  There's good reason for there being rocks or mulch under most downspouts. Moss might work if the foot traffic is light, though fast water can dislodge moss and it needs long periods of moist weather for at least part of the year.

Answer (score 1):

Bricks, pavers or rocks, and moss and/or lichen to grow on them would be my suggestion if you're trying to grow plants there.